# GNU Debugger sometimes terminates with KeyboardInterrupt?

Tags: docker, gdb

Sporadically GDB running interactively in a docker container terminates, caused by a supposed KeyboardInterrupt (though I didn't enter anything). Sometimes even when starting:

```
Reading symbols from ./Main...
Exception ignored in: <gdb._GdbOutputFile object at 0x7fb993b97880>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py", line 43, in flush
    def flush(self):
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

What might be the cause of this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the result of SIGTERM -- there's a [bug report for it](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29185). In my case, the SIGTERM was coming from the out-of-memory killer, so it also seemed 'random' and unexpected.